# Conditional string replacement based on matched column

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I'd like to match a string present in a columnX and replace with a fixed string in columnY. For example how to match strings based on column3 in file1 with file2 in the below example and selectively replace column2 of file1 with fixed string "AU" whenever a match is found. If no match is found, then those rows in file1 should be printed as is to output. Both file1 & file2 contains more than 100K such lines.

File1:

```
0,DS,"C_3363/Y"
1,DS,"C_3363/Y"
0,UU,"C_3364/Y"
1,UU,"C_3364/Y"
```

File2

```
0, "C_3364/Y"
1, "C_3364/Y"
```

Desired output:

```
0,DS,"C_3363/Y"
1,DS,"C_3363/Y"
0,AU,"C_3364/Y"
1,AU,"C_3364/Y"
```

Comment: `File2` has 2 identical records. What is the logic in the matching and expected output if `File2` was `"C_3364/Y"\n"C_3363/Y"\n`?

Comment: File2 will have unique column1 similar to File1. Updated the question.

Comment: So the question now is: How to modify `$2` in `File1` if `$1` and `$3` match `$1`and `$2` in `File2`?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter to match $1 of both files as every matched line based on $3 should result in a fixed string replacement (ie AU instead of UU)

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably not the right place for your question.

Comment: Tried below awk but couldn't successfully keep unmatched rows for (column = 3; column <= NF; ++column) {
        if ($column == ",") {
            $column = $2
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another gnu **awk** solution with single FS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {FS=","}
NR==FNR && sub(/ /, "", $2) {a[$2]++; next}
($3 in a){ printf "%s,AU,%s\n", $1,$3; next}1
```

same, **commandline**:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR && sub(/[[:space:]]/,"",$2){a[$2]++; next} ($3 in a){ printf "%s,AU,%s\n", $1,$3; next}1' input2.txt input1.txt
```

with input files:

```
$ cat input2.txt
0, "C_3364/Y"
1, "C_3364/Y"
1, "A_3364/Y"
1, "B_3364/Y"

$ cat input1.txt
0,DS,"C_3363/Y"
1,DS,"C_3363/Y"
0,UU,"C_3364/Y"
1,UU,"C_3364/Y"
```

you'll get:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR && sub(/[[:space:]]/,"",$2){a[$2]++; next} ($3 in a){ printf "%s,AU,%s\n", $1,$3; next}1' input2.txt input1.txt
0,DS,"C_3363/Y"
1,DS,"C_3363/Y"
0,AU,"C_3364/Y"
1,AU,"C_3364/Y"
```